# If I replace teapot object of Vuforia iOS project, why only triangle seen instead of Cube?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, blender, vuforia

I downloaded sample Vuforia iOS project. Instead of teapot, I want to rotate a Cube with texture. To create a cube having texture, I used blender and created a OBJ file with its UV mapping image as below:

[image]

In blender, it renders perfect and I can see the cube object with its texture perfectly.

Then I converted OBJ file to .h file using perl script and replaced that Teapot.h file and also replaced teapot image with PNG I attached above.

While I run the project, the cube is seen with its texture but triangles are cut for each side as below:

[image]

I am desperate to create custom squares, cubes having textures in existing iOS project but, I am not getting success in checking feasibility.

> NOTE: My project is already developed with lots of frameworks and
>   libraries and in one screen, I need to integrate this function.

Comment: check your normals, also triangulate before exporting.

Comment: I did not understand, can u explain?

Comment: depending on what you dont understand it might be a bit much to explain here, please refer to the manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html - in general, unity only displays one side of a face, the one the normal points out of - and to triangulate you can either add a triangulation modifier and apply or just press ctrl+t.

Comment: @yes I'm pretty sure you should only work with quads when exporting to any 3d engine. As Unity already does the triangulation for you, doing it yourself before is not recommended AFAIK

Comment: @yes: Where I need to do this: `you can either add a triangulation modifier and apply or just press ctrl+t.`

Comment: triangulation modifier on the modifier stack (the exporter will then apply it if you tick apply modifiers - its the better, non-destructive way) or if you want to manually turn it to tris you press ctrl+t in edit mode.

Comment: @Jichael in 99% of cases it probably doesnt matter, but if unity decides to triangulate a face differently it might look of for normal maps or animations. other than that quality or performance wise it should make no difference whatsoever.

Comment: also @NSPratik usually the problem with normals will be fixed if in edit mode you either click "recalculate normals" (in the left sidebar thingy under shading/uv) or use the hotkey ctrl+n

Comment: What I need to do? Recalculate normals or apply triangulation modifier?

Comment: @NSPratik the problem in question is probably (99% sure) due to misaligned normals. triangulation before exporting is just good practice. but you know, you can always make a backup and just try out things before asking (meant jokingly, not offensive) :D

Comment: @yes, sure I will do the same and get back to you..

Comment: Can you give me some clue on how to do triangulation in Blender? It will help me as I have not used Blender ever. Will I have to do it for all side or whatever steps..

Comment: yes i would triangulate the whole mesh. id use the modifier and only apply triangulation when exporting (when you click export there is a checkbox "apply modifiers" in the lower left ) as its non-destructive within blender. if you dont care about that though, just go to edit mode (tab), select the whole mesh (a until everything is orange) and apply triangulation (ctrl+t)

Comment: Thanks a lot @yes. I have understood what you say. I will try to perform it on Monday and will get back to you..!

Comment: @yes As there are just triangles are seen, it seems that the problem is with triangulation. How you are sure that the problem is not triangulation but it is due to normals? If just normals is the issue, will it work if I just click on ‘recalculate normals’ option?

Comment: because unity culls the back of faces (unlike blender's renderer) and the face normal is what differentiates between front and backside. but tbh it might be a problem with both since when you import geometry that is not tris only, it gets automatically triangulated as game engines only deal with triangles, so maybe when triangulation on unity side happens you somehow end up with incorrect normals. thus why i said, check the normals and triangulate before export.

Comment: you can display normals in the 'n' sidebar (the right side one) in edit mode (you want to display face-normals). its in 'mesh display' category. to see them well you might also need to turn up their size. but ultimatively, you will need to try it out, back up your .blend file and test it. if you need a more visual aid, there are tutorials on youtube.

Comment: Big question is, how can I check the normals and be sure that they are ok?

Comment: Can there be issue while converting OBJ file to .h file as I am using perl script for it?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, actually I was wondering I will have to check my .h file to be sure normals are ok. But now I came to know that I need to check normals in Blender and check faces are on viewer side..

Comment: @yes I applied triangulation modifier and now, object seen perfect square. Now issue is, 3 sides are seen black while 3 sides have perfect texture. I don't understand what is wrong because in blender, I can see all sides having texture and also normals of all sides are pointing outwards..

Comment: @yes I have achieved what I was looking for. Thanks for your tremendous support and I came to know lots of things from you. Please check my detailed answer for the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could achieve it by having add-on to Blender and then export `.h` file directly from Blender. There is no need to do triangulate before exporting as `Unity` already does the triangulation for us.

- Download add-on from [here](https://github.com/StickyBeat/BlenderVuforiaExport). There is total guide on how to add it to the Blender.
- Prepare the 3D object that you want in Blender. Check [this](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/cs420/lecture/blender1/BlenderTutorial1.html) tutorial which explains how to use Blender and make a simple 3D object having a texture around it.
- Once you have the model that you want, go to `File` > `Export` > `Vuforia OpenGL C Include` as shown in below image. Save the `.h` file at some location

[image]

- In Vuforia iOS sample project, add this `.h` file and `UV-mapping` image (which we used to render our object) same way `Teapot.h` and its `UV-mapping` image.
- Import the header file.
- Replace Teapot:

Replace

> ```
> glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)teapotVertices);
> glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)teapotNormals);
> glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)teapotTexCoords);
> ```

with

> ```
> BlenderExportedObject object = rectObject;
>
> glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)object.vertices);
> glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)object.normals);
> glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)object.texCoords);
> ```

where `rectObject` is object name. In my case, my Blender object name was `rect` so it created `rectObject` name in `.h` file. Check your `.h` file for find that name.

- Draw elements:

Replace

> ```
> glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_TEAPOT_OBJECT_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)teapotIndices);
> ```

with

> ```
> glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_RECT_OBJECT_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)object.indices);
> ```

Refer to `.h` file to find `NUM_RECT_OBJECT_INDEX`.

- That's all. It should now render any complex 3D object flawlessly.